# Ordering By a Decimal / String in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a string ordering in CakePHP but I've some mistakes with this. I've strings like C.110, C.100.1, ..., C.100.8.

When I try to order using:

```
ORDER BY CAST(plane_accounts.code AS DECIMAL(10,5))
```

MySQL returns me some like:

```
C.110
C.110.8
C.110.1
C.100.2
```

Someone know how to resolve this? Thank's for help.

Comment: This looks like a SQL problem, could you post the full query?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use ORDER BY (plane_accounts.code)?  Also, this appears to have nothing to do with CakePHP - just a MySQL question.  If you get the MySQL working, THEN ask about CakePHP if you  don't understand how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to cast it, a plain ASC sort on the `code` field should just work:

```
$this->PlaneAccount->find('all', array(
    'order' => array(
        'PlaneAccount.code' => 'ASC'
    )
));
```

Or in plain MySQL syntax:

```
SELECT `code` FROM `plane_accounts` ORDER BY `code` ASC;
```

Comment: Hey everybody, hold on. I know how to do this using CakePHP and obviously I tried to do this using just `ORDER BY plane_accounts.code`.

But... when I do this the return was:
`5, A, B, B.100, C.110, C.110.1, C.110.10, C.110.11, C.110.2, C.110.3`
Can you see now the problem? I try to use CAST to correctly order this strings.

Comment: That still doesn't change anything. The data you mentioned above will still be put in that order if you just do a plain ASC order on the code field. Otherwise, you should be more clear on what order you get now and what you would expect.

Comment: Flávio Ricardo - what's the problem with that order?  It looks correct.  Per Oldskool, post what you're getting AND what you're hoping for - that will help a LOT in getting you the answer you're hoping for.